# FB API making insecure xd_arbiter.php requests in a secure page

Tags: https, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having trouble with a secure Facebook app page which the browser reports as containing insecure content.

The insecure content seems to be one request to:
    http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php

All subsequent calls from the FB API are going over https, though.

I can't figure out what the problem is, since I'm loading all of my content securely, including the FB script:
    https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Seems like it's Facebook's own mistake, and a fix is on the way: 
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303558613049120?browse=search_4f874a5f45e924383360019

Comment: Having the exact same problem.  It pops up the "Insecure Content Warning" alert in IE8, driving my clients wild.

Comment: link does not work for me.  Might just be my work browser though...

Answer (score 3):

It's a Facebook problem. Fix should be coming soon and there's nothing you can do in the meantime.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303558613049120?browse=search_4f877beec69e35d32059456

Comment: This link does not work. I find it very inappropriate that Facebook would simply make bug links disappear. All bug pages should be preserved forever for posterity. Now there is important information that developers simply can't access. This is another example of Facebook being completely disconnected from the needs of developers using its APIs.