# Chrome thinks FB dialogues are popups and blocks them

Tags: c#, facebook, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, popup

Alright. I'm working on a facebook game using Unity(C#). For some reason, the first time the user tries to do an app request chrome blocks the fb dialogue box as a popup. IE, FF, Opera, and Safari don't do this. Now if the user uses another browser to give permission the first time. All subsequent app requests work fine in chrome.

Now obviously if I were just a user, I'd just white list it. But as a dev, I've been tasked to figure out why and get rid of the issue. I've scavenged through google results as well as the threads here on stack overflow and haven't been able to find anything similar.

Any code or other info you need to better help, let me know and I'll post it.

thx,

Gordon

Comment: Is this for a web site, canvas application, or maybe something else?

Comment: This seems like more of a web applications question than a programming question.  And the solution will be related more to web design.

Comment: Are you sure you running the code creating new window on user interaction, like click and not in some asynchronous callback?

Comment: Nitzan Tomer: It's a Unity3D game played on facebook.


Ben Voigt: It's not web design because the call is programmed into the game to make a call to facebook.


Juicy Scripter: It is technically a click, but an in game click which makes a call to fb to bring up the fb dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

... comment != answer ...

To be clear here:

- The call comes from a click in the Unity Web Player
- It calls the Application.ExternalCall() method in order to call the Facebook Javascript SDK that's been injected into the canvas

Are there any Javascript errors apparent?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PkzQ2aCg

not sure what the abriter is.

I replaced our actual domain with "DOMAINOFTHEGAME" just for nda sake.

Comment: Looks like it's certainly related to the http/https distinction, there were some issues with it last month (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131481/fb-api-making-insecure-xd-arbiter-php-requests-in-a-secure-page)

Comment: Although that seems to be happening independently of any dialog requests - in some cases repeatedly with seemingly no user interaction.

Comment: The js error I'm having has been happening rapidly since my original post. in the 72000 occurences range and the game is just idleing there.